# setting path of dojo libnrary

Tags: javascript, dojo

what shold be the directory structure that i should follow while using dojo.
My webpage is A.html placed in directory sample.
Sample contails A.html, JS
JS contails all dojo filese DIGIT,DOJO,DOJOX

what code shold i use inside A.html to import this libraries

Answer (score 0):

The recommended directory layout may look like this:

```
-- A.html
-- js
   -- dojo
        -- dojo
           -- dojo.js
        -- dijit
        -- dojox
```

You can use `<script>` tag to include the `dojo.js` in your html file, e.g. `<script src='js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js'></script>`